# X++ Reserved Column Name?

Tags: x++

I am receiving a syntax error when referencing a column in a custom table.  Unfortunately, renaming the column is not an option.  It is in locked isv code.

My guess is that "Setting" is actually some sort of reserved term when working with a table.

Anyone see this before?  Any workaround?

[image]

Thanks,

- Brad

Comment: FYI: Creating a field with this name is no longer possible in AX365.

Comment: Probably because it is a [key word](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/x-keywords). You can try to use the `@` escape character so that it is not recognized as keyword (see https://community.dynamics.com/ax/f/microsoft-dynamics-ax-forum/81946/ax-2012-select-statement-for-a-field-name-using-reserved-word/152615 for an example).

Comment: Using @Setting worked for the select statement, but still the same issue when attempting to use the value.

Comment: Reserved by the *update_recordset* statment ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a dirty workaround you could try to access the field like so

```
MyTable tb;
...    
info(tb.(fieldName2Id(tableNum(MyTable), 'Setting')));
```

Comment: Sneaky..  (and ugly, as you mentioned) but works great.